# Remote API for authorization and registration from mobile client

Tags: android, ios, rest, security, https

I am looking for the best way, the most secure way to build Client-Server communication.
I have simple web site where I can login and sign up using well-known web secure implementation.
But I need to create standalone mobile client Android/iOS and make it possible to do the same (log in,sign up) from mobile client.
As far as mobile client will be native, not just mobile version of page. I need to create secure communication between client and server.

I have already implemented several projects using REST API with tokens over https, but it seems that there is better way to do this.

What is the most secure way to implement client server communication in this way.
Also in my case creating something like OAuth server doesn't make any sense because client communicating with server directly and I don't need to give some access to other apps like in OAuth.

1. Use web view but only for logging in and registering, of course on special mobile pages.
2. Just use https and REST API as I have done previously
3. Create some encrypted channel directly with TCP and sockets

I have no more IDEAS how to implement this, maybe someone can suggest how to do this or at least how this is done in apps like facebook, amazon, aliexpress .....

Thanks.